# How to convert sets of wav files to .sf2 format

Tags: python-2.7, wav, soundfont

I have an instrument program written in python that creates 88 .wav files for a set of instruments. I am trying to convert these .wave files to .sf2 so that I can read it into a piano program I stumbled across. Are there ways to do this using code on python or other languages? I've seen a lot of posts that convert .sf2 to .wav but not the reverse.

Comment: If Google search didn't return any good results then I'm afraid you have to write all the code and reverse engineer the soundfont format yourself. The package `sf2utils` is not of any help to you?

Comment: I was only able to find expensive software or ones that don' work on macs. I'm not sure how to start using sf2utils since it takes in .sf2 files as input.

Comment: My advice: if it is only one sf2 you need to create then search for someone who can do it for you on one of the many music producer forums out there. (or spend the $)